# Android seekbar thumb shadow

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm trying to create custom seekbar like this:
[Example of the thumb with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2zeE.png)

I can't create such shadow for the thumb. I tried to draw the shadow as a part of the custom thumb in xml, but it moves the thumb up.

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_shadow"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:height="@dimen/seek_bar_thumb_shadow_size"
        android:width="@dimen/seek_bar_thumb_shadow_size"
        android:top="@dimen/seek_bar_thumb_shadow_distance"
        >
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_red" android:bottom="@dimen/seek_bar_thumb_shadow_distance"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:height="@dimen/seek_bar_thumb_size"
        android:width="@dimen/seek_bar_thumb_size"
        >
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Example of the current thumb:
[Current thumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUmd2.png)

Could you please help me with this? How to create such shadow correctly?

p.s. don't look at wrong colors, please.
Thank you.